# Delay and animate background

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to make a background image disappear. It works.
But it fails when I try to delay it or to animate it. 
Any guess what it's wrong and how to do it well?

```
$(function(){      
    $("#foto1").click(function() {
        $("#foto1").delay(1000).animate.css({"background":"none"},2000);
    }); 
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78W3u/

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Remove the background from an element, hide the element completely, or change the opacity of the element?

Comment: I want to Delay 1seg and then fadeOut (or animate in some way) the png of the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fadeout an image : http://jsfiddle.net/2MQeC/

```
$(function(){      
    $("#foto1").click(function() {
        $("#foto1").fadeOut(2000);
    }); 
})​
```

**-- EDIT --**

This will animate the background independently of the image : http://jsfiddle.net/2MQeC/1/

```
#foto1 { 
    background: black; 
  -webkit-transition: background 1.5s ease;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
     -moz-transition: background 1.5s ease;  /* FF4+ */
      -ms-transition: background 1.5s ease;  /* IE10 */
       -o-transition: background 1.5s ease;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
          transition: background 1.5s ease;
}
```

​

```
$(function(){      
    $("#foto1").click(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.css({
                background: 'green'
            });
        }, 1000); // delay
    }); 
})​;
```

As you can see, this rely on [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions) for background animation.

A better cross browser solution would be to use jQuery `.animate()` function.
But you can't modify as many properties as `.css()` could.

Extract from jQuery `.animate()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

> Most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic
>   jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be
>   animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).

However, you could change your markup and separate your image and your background in two div who are superimposed. This could simplify what you are trying to do.

Comment: In this example the div and the background are the same just because I simplified the case to explain it. But I am asking how to "delay and animate the background" Jorge answers delay and fadeOut the div not the background

Answer (score 1):

Tried like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $("#foto1").click(function() {
       $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(20000, function(){
        $("#foto1").css('background', 'none')   //<=== this remove the background after the animation stops
       });
    });    
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78W3u/5/

Comment: This delay and fadeOut the div. I was asking to delay and animate or fadeOut the background. In my example the two are the same, I just simplified the case to explain it (In my real case there are other things in the div)